# How to fix 'Cannot invoke method buildTypes()' error in the android studio while it is syncing the Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

As I remember I haven't edited anything in my Gradle and suddenly I realized I can not sync project Gradle anymore,
this error is shown to me: 
`ERROR: Cannot invoke method buildTypes() on null object`

I've searched about my problem in StackOverflow and find some similar questions but none of the works for me

this is my Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.test"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27

        //todo: change the versionCode and the versionName before upload in store
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.4.0"
        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }

    } buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

}
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

I have no idea how to fix it so I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `buildTypes` statement to the next line.

Use

```
} 
buildTypes {
```

instead of

```
} buildTypes {
```